# Issue - after I updated PHP version

Tags: php, linux, inotify

I had PHP 7.033 and the inotify PHP extension and my script worked fine... then I decided to update PHP version to 7.4, and then I see -

> Call to undefined function inotify_init().

I applied all advice how to change/add it to `php.ini`. I tried to add `inotify.so`, so I think the problem is that inotify is located here `/usr/lib/php/20151012/inotify.so`, but in fact it is trying to find inotify here and it doesn't exist here `/usr/lib/php/20190902/inotify.so`

I tried to install inotify and it says "failed to install, it was installed already version 2.0.0"

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Add a symlink to the search location or change your extension_dir in php.ini so it matches the correct path to look for extensions.
Which option you choose depends on whether PHP is looking in the wrong directory for all your extensions or if it's only this one that's in the wrong place.